# opencv and importing cv2 on Windows

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

I would love to get your advices: I just finished install open cv using "pip install opencv-python" on both computer terminal and on vscode. But still it doesn't appear cv2 for importing on my vscode editor here.

I don't have enough points. this is the image that include my dir to the opencv:

[image]

Comment: 1. Verify that vscode is using the python where opencv was installed, 2. Close and reopen vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the base environment of the anaconda? You can get which python interpreter you are using on the status bar at the bottom-left in the VSCode.

[image]

If you don't want to switch to this anaconda environemnt, you need to recreate a terminal with the shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+`**, and then install the **opencv-python** again.